# Show and hide a column based on value in filter in worksheet - Tableau 2022

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am new to Tableau development and have a requirement to show a column in the worksheet based on the value in a filter (unique value shown from the SQL table).

Let's say in the filter if I have selected "A" then I have to show all the columns and if I selected "B" then I have to hide 1 column in the worksheet.

Comment: This question is rather brief and may close in its current state. Could you edit your question to show where in the documentation you are looking?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this with the parameter in two different views.

If conditions first get enabled then View1 should show. else View2 should show.